# What is the difference between timeout and open timeout?

Tags: ruby, rest-client

In the Ruby RestClient gem, what's the difference between the timeout and open-timeout functionality?

http://www.ruby-doc.org/gems/docs/w/wgibbs-rest-client-1.0.5/RestClient/Resource.html#method-i-open_timeout

I didn't get anything from the doc file of the gem either.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You're reading the wrong documentation (yours is for [wgibbs-rest-client](http://rubygems.org/gems/wgibbs-rest-client) which has not been updated since 2009): [here's the right one](http://rubydoc.info/github/rest-client/rest-client/frames). But that one does not say anything about the difference either, although it is simple:

`:open_timeout` is the timeout for opening the connection. This is useful if you are calling servers with slow or shaky response times.

`:timeout` is the timeout for reading the answer. This is useful to make sure you will not get stuck half way in the reading process, or get stuck reading a 5 MB file when you're expecting 5 KB of `JSON`.

Comment: Thanks....Just to confirm response = RestClient.get "abc/order_items/advanced_search?" would be equivalent to response = RestClient::Request.execute(:method => :get, :url => "abc/order_items/advanced_search?", :timeout => 300)

Comment: Yes, `RestClient.get` is calling `execute` like this: `Request.execute(:method => :get, :url => url, :headers => headers, &block)`